# Oracle report, add currency symbol after values

Tags: oracle, currency, oraclereports

If I add currency symbol to values it's look like: `$5000`, I want that currency symbol will be after value: `5000$`, possible to format ?

Comment: Documentation here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements004.htm#i34510

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
select to_char(5000, '9999l'), to_char(5000, 'l9999')
from dual
```

[Here is a sqlfiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/8669)

---

If you don't want to specify the length you can do (I don't like this solution...):

```
select substr(trim(to_char('1', 'l9')), 1, 1) || 5000
from dual
```

[Here is another sqlfiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/8686)

Comment: @Lopezito, how do you get your foramt currently ?